# How to access the "arguments" literal object of an outer function from a closure?

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I have a closure, and from that closure, I need to access the `arguments` object literal of the function in which the closure is defined:

```
function outerFunction(){

    var myClosure = function(){
        // I need to access the "arguments" object of "outerFunction"
    }

}
```

Is this possible without storing `arguments` in a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: Just use a variable. There's no good reason *not* to.

> Is this possible without storing arguments in a variable?

Your options are either to store a reference to the `arguments` object itself, or use variables (or arguments) to refer to individual items from it, but you can't access the `arguments` object, itself, of your outer function from within your inner function because its own `arguments` shadows it.

There is one very limited situation in which you could do it without doing either of those things: *During* the call to `outerFunction` (not later, if `myClosure` survives `outerFuntion` returning) you could use `outerFunction.arguments`. I don't think that's *documented* behavior (at least, I can't find it in the spec), but it works on Chrome, Firefox, and IE11. E.g.:

```js
function outerFunction() {

  var myClosure = function(where) {
    snippet.log(where + " " + JSON.stringify(outerFunction.arguments));
  };

  myClosure("Inside");

  return myClosure;
}

var c = outerFunction(1, 2, 3);
c("Outside");
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

I see **no reason to do that**, and again I don't think it's actually in the spec (I think it's unspecified behavior some code way back relied on and so browsers copied). But it does work on at least some engines provided you do it *during* the call to `outerFunction`.

---

In comments you've said

> I would like to call it directly in order to automatise a task

That's exactly what assigning it to a variable does for you, it makes it possible to use the outer function's `arguments` from within the inner function:

```js
function outerFunction() {
  var args = arguments;

  var myClosure = function() {
    snippet.log(JSON.stringify(args));
  };

  return myClosure;
}

var c = outerFunction(1, 2, 3);
c();
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```